# Java: Dissecting a string

Tags: java, string, file

I have content inside of a file and I am trying to dissect certain portions of said content.

Inside of file:
FNAME:John:LNAME:Doe:AGE:40:DOB:July 31, 1975

*This is all on one line*

Now, I am wanting to only get as output:

- John Doe 40 July 31, 1975

The current output is:

- John:LNAME:DOE:AGE:40:DOB:July 31, 1975

I've tried using:

```
System.out.println(line.substring(line.indexOf(":") + 1, line.lastIndexOf(":")));
```

but that only cuts out "FNAME:" and nothing else.

I hope this is explained in enough detail and I apologize if it is not. Thank you for your help.

Code:

```
Scanner cfg_reader = new Scanner(cfg_file);
        cfg_reader.useDelimiter("~");

        while (cfg_reader.hasNext()) {
            String line = cfg_reader.next();
            System.out.println(line.substring(line.indexOf(":") + 1, line.lastIndexOf(":")));
            //System.out.println(cfg_reader.next());
        }
```

Keep in mind, this is my current code and what I've provided you above my code selection is different from what this is.

Comment: What did you try so far? What did not work?

Comment: I tried using the delimiter of the Scanner and that worked just a little bit but did not achieve what I wanted exactly. It split everything before the delimiter onto another line as I expected. Then I tried the while loop and substring(line.indexOf(":"))[...] but that gave me John:LNAME:[...etcetera].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split strings using a regex with the method ['split'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) which will create an array of strings split on that char.

So from your example `line.split(":")` will produce an array:

```
{"FNAME", "John", "LNAME", "Doe", "AGE", "40", "DOB", "July 31, 1975"}
```

You can then iterate over it and build the output you want

For example:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        String line = "FNAME:John:LNAME:Doe:AGE:40:DOB:July 31, 1975";

        final String[] split = line.split(":");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                builder.append(split[i]);
                if (i != split.length -1) {
                    builder.append(" ");
                }
            }
        }
        assertThat(builder.toString(), is(equalTo("John Doe 40 July 31, 1975")));
    }
}
```

There's undoubtably a better way of doing it, but wine..

Comment: Why muddy the answer with unit testing stuff? Just have the answer, without extras.

Comment: Why not provide an answer where they can copy/paste/run and have it verified without question that it works?

Comment: If they just *run it*, then they have verified without question that it works. That, and a simple dose of glancing at the answer, are all they need.